# Lightning button to update a record

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, button, napili

My use case is to have a button inside a Salesforce Napili Community, which updates the Case.Status field of the record displayed

The logic for the button should be quite simple:

- IF Case.IsClosed = 'True' - button text to read "Closed" - button disabled
- IF Case.Status = 'New' or 'Awaiting Customer' - button text to read "Submit" - on click updates Case.Status to 'Submitted'
- ELSE button text to read "Withdraw Case" - on click updates Case.Status to 'Withdrawn'

I have been struggling with creating this Lightning Component / Apex class with no luck, so thought I'd reach out to see if anyone can help at all? (Please)

Unfortunately I am not a developer so swimming in the deep end. My current code currently doesn't even let me put the button on the Community page as I get the error "Unable to parse JSON response" so it's very wrong.

Component

```
<aura:component controller="UpdateCaseStatusController_LC" implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
     <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}"/>
     <aura:attribute name="case" type="Case"/>
     <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String"/>

<ui:button aura:id="mybtn" class="slds-button slds-button--brand slds-size--1-of-1" label="{!v.case.Status}" press="{!c.onclick}" disabled="{!v.case.IsClosed == true ? 'true' : 'false'}"/>
</aura:component>
```

Controller:

```
({    
init : function(component, event, helper) {
    var action = component.get("c.getCase");
    action.setParams({"recordId": component.get("v.recordId")});

    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if(component.isValid() && state == "SUCCESS"){
            var c = response.getReturnValue();
            component.set("v.case", c);
            window.setTimeout(
                $A.getCallback(function () {
                    var button = component.find("mybtn");
                    if(c.Status == "New" || c.Status == "Awaiting Customer"){
                        button.set("v.label","Submit");
                    }else if(c.Status == "Closed"){
                        button.set("v.label","Closed");
                    }else {
                        button.set("v.label","Withdraw Case");
                    }
                })
            );    

        } else {
            console.log('There was a problem : '+response.getError());
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},

onclick : function(component, event, helper) {
    var action = component.get("c.saveCase");
        action.setParams({"recordId": component.get("v.recordId")});
    if (callback) {
        action.setCallback(this, callback);
    }
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
})
```

Apex:

```
public class UpdateCaseStatusController_LC {

@AuraEnabled
public static Case getCase(Id recordId){
    Case caseRec = [SELECT Id, isClosed, Status FROM Case WHERE id=:recordId];
    return caseRec;
}

@AuraEnabled
public static Case saveCase(Id recordId){
    Case caseRec = [SELECT Id, Status FROM Case WHERE id=:recordId];

    if (caseRec.Status == 'New' || caseRec.Status == 'Awaiting Customer') {
        caseRec.Status = 'Submitted';
    } else {
        caseRec.Status = 'Withdrawn';
    }

    update caseRec;
    return caseRec;
}}
```

Comment: You are passing 2 params in method saveCase. It takes only one of type Case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of things, Your getCase method returns an object of type "case", But, you are setting the object to a String in the init method of your js Controller.Additionally, as N.B pointed out, you seem to be passing 2 arguments when your apex method saveCase is expecting only one argument of type case.

Below is a refined version of your logic for your use-case. I have hard-coded "recordId" for demo purposes, do modify as required. And I notice that you have used individual aura:attributes for properties such as Status and Closed. Instead we ought to use compound attributes such as Object or Array of Objects for better logic.

**Component:**

```
<aura:component controller="SampleCaseController" implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="case" type="Case"/>

    <ui:button aura:id="mybtn" class="slds-button slds-button--brand" label="{!v.case.Status}" press="{!c.onclick}" disabled="{!v.case.IsClosed == true ? 'true' : 'false'}"/>

</aura:component>
```

We could have used **aura:if** for conditional rendering of status just like how we have used for "disabled" attribute. However extensive usage of aura:if is not recommended. Hence we will do our conditional checks in JS Controllers.

**Apex Controller :**

```
public class SampleCaseController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static Case getCase(Id recordId){
        Case mycase = [SELECT Id, isClosed, Status FROM Case WHERE id=:recordId];
        return mycase;
    }
}
```

**Controller.js :**

```
({
    init : function(component, event, helper) {
        var recordId = "50061000007fHbf"; // for demo purpose

        var action = component.get("c.getCase");
        action.setParams({"recordId": recordId});

        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if(component.isValid() && state == "SUCCESS"){
                var c = response.getReturnValue();
                component.set("v.case", c);
                window.setTimeout(
                    $A.getCallback(function () {
                        var button = component.find("mybtn");
                        if(c.Status == "New" || c.Status == "Awaiting Customer"){
                            button.set("v.label","Submit");
                        }else if(c.Status == "Closed"){
                            button.set("v.label","Closed");
                        }else {
                            button.set("v.label","Withdraw Case");
                        }

                    })
                );

            } else {
                console.log('There was a problem : '+response.getError());
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);

    },
    onclick : function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log("Your save logic goes here");
    }

})
```

We will require **window.setTimeout** to provide small delay during the aura render cycle. If not the updated values will not reflect in the DOM.

**Results :**

[image: New Status]

When Status is new, the button text is set to "Submit"

[image: New Community]

[image: Working Status]

Status anything other than New or Awaiting Customer, the text is set to "Withdraw Case"

[image: Withdrawn Community]

Status Changed to Closed

[image: Closed Status]

Button Disabled in the Community and Status changed to closed

[image: Closed Community]

**Update :**

Change the methods below as shown and your save method should work during onclick.

**Apex Controller :**

```
@AuraEnabled
public static Case saveCase(Case caseRec){

        if (caseRec.Status == 'New' || caseRec.Status == 'Awaiting Customer') {
            caseRec.Status = 'Submitted';
        } else {
            caseRec.Status = 'Withdrawn';
        }

        update caseRec;
        return caseRec;
    }
```

I have changed the parameter from RecordId to caseRec as to avoid an additional database query.

**Controller.js :**

```
onclick : function(component, event, helper) {

        var action = component.get("c.saveCase");
        action.setParams({"caseRec": component.get("v.case")});

        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if(component.isValid() && state == "SUCCESS"){
                var c = response.getReturnValue();
                component.set("v.case", c);
            } else {
                console.log('There was a problem : '+response.getError());
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);

}
```

The other components do not require any change. The status would display as expected.

**Results :**

When status is set to working

[image: Working Status]

The status is set to Withdraw case in community :

[image: Withdrawn Community]

When you click on withdraw case, the button text and case status change to **"Withdrawn"**

[image: Withdrawn]
[image: Case Status Withdrawn]

Comment: Thanks Sumuga, that's gold. However, I am still struggling with getting the button to save the record with an updated status, & also for the button to use the status of the case displayed. I've updated my code above. Can you help again please?

Comment: @Howard : I have updated the answer. Change the couple of methods shown above and rest should work fine.

Comment: @Howard : Hope it resolved your queries.

Comment: Thank you loads  Sumuga, this worked perfectly, and I now understand what I had wrong so you have improved my knowledge as well. Thanks

Comment: Note that the variable name in `action.setParams()` must match the variable name in the declaration of the Apex method - in this case "caseRec". That tripped me up.

Comment: Hi ,I have similar kind of requirement,Here one question is when i change my Status then button label is not changing automatically... I need to refresh the page

Answer (score 0):

i have a similar requirement. I am using a lightning component behind a button on quote object(custom object). when user click on this button if quote status is approved show user a alert that quote is already approved if its not approve then change quote status to approve. Below is my code i am getting attempt to de reference null object.

component:

controller:
public class ApproveQuoteController 
{
    @AuraEnabled
    public static FConnect__Service_Quote__c getQuote(Id quoteId)
    {
        return [select id,name,FConnect__Account__c,FConnect__Status__c,FConnect__Contact__c,FConnect__Site__c,FConnect__Problem__c
                   from FConnect__Service_Quote__c where id=:quoteId];
    }

```
@AuraEnabled
public static FConnect__Service_Quote__c saveQuote(FConnect__Service_Quote__c quote){

    quote.FConnect__Status__c = 'Approved';

    update quote;
    return quote;
}
```

}
JS:
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {

```
        var action = component.get("c.saveQuote");
        var action2 = component.get("c.getServerSideMessage");
        action.setParams({"quote": component.get("v.quote")});

        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if(component.isValid() && state == "SUCCESS"){
                var c = response.getReturnValue();
                component.set("v.quote", c);
            }
            else if (state === "ERROR"){
                var errors = action2.getError();
                if (errors) {
                    if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                        cmp.set(“v.message”, errors[0].message);
                    }
                }
            }    
            else {
                console.log('There was a problem : '+response.getError());
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);

}
```

})